# Optimal LinqToSql GroupBy query, in 1:m relationship

Tags: c#, performance, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two database tables (connected with relation 1:m):


Location (locId, locName)

1, USA

2, Germany

3, Spain

Sublocations (subLocId, subLocName, locId)

1, Denver, 1

2, Detroit, 1

3, New York, 1

4, Hamburg, 2

5, Berlin, 2

6, Munich, 2

7, Madrid, 3

8, Barcelona, 3

9, Valencia, 3

With using Linq to Sql, I need to fill the LocationDto, like this:
LocationDto (locId, subLocId, name)

1, null, USA

1, 1, Denver

1, 2, Detroit

1, 3, New York

2,null, Germany

2, 4, Hamburg

2, 5, Berlin

2, 6, Munich

3,null, Spain

3, 7, Madrid

3, 8, Barcelona

3, 9, Valencia

Comment: So that's just a union of the sublocation table as-is with location extended with the null field and then sorted? Are you changing data types too? Can you see how to select both the sublocation and location tables into a LocationDto? Then union and sort!

Comment: Yes, but it's not so simple, I need optimal Linq2Sql syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new class to hold the joined objects:

```
public class JoinedLocations
{
    public int locId{get;set;}
    public int? subLocId{get;set;}
    public string Description{get;set;}
}
```

and then run this query

```
var query = 
Location
.GroupJoin
(
    Sublocations.DefaultIfEmpty(),
    l=>l.locId,
    s=>s.locId,
    (l,s)=>new {l,s}
)
.SelectMany
(
    x=>
    x.s.DefaultIfEmpty
    (
        new Sublocations
        {
            subLocId=-1,
            subLocName="",
            locId=-1
        }
    ),
    (l,s)=> 
    new JoinedLocations
    {
        locId=l.l.locId,
        subLocId=s.subLocId,
        Description = (s.subLocId==-1?l.l.locName:s.subLocName)
    }
)
.Union
(
    loc
    .Select
    (
        x=>
        new JoinedLocations
        {
            locId=x.locId,
            subLocId=null,
            Description = x.locName
        }
    )
)
.OrderBy(x=>x.locId)
.ThenBy (x => x.subLocId)
```

This will give you the results you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your answer but I think there is a little problem. If location has sublocations, only sublocations are returned (not the location). 
For example: 
1, null, USA 
1, 1, Denver 
1, 2, Detroit 
1, 3, New York

1, null, USA is not returned.

However, if location doesn't have any sublocations, than the location is returned.

Comment: I will check and update accordingly....

Comment: any ideas what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Sorry, i had to go. Well the issue, is that because of how your data is, if you left join you will get these results. The solution would be to union the results of this query with the Location table, but that would mean having a strongly typed object than an anonymous. I will let you know tomorrow.